# Cant reduce bold size of header 1

Tags: css, html, web, header

I am trying to make the font in h1 less bold. It seems like the letters are just to fat.

CSS:

```
h1 {color: #FFFFFF; font-family: ballparkweiner; font-size: 110px;
text-align: center; margin: 0px; }

@font-face {
    font-family: 'ballparkweiner';
    src: url('ballw___.eot');
    src: url('ballw___.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('ballw___.woff') format('woff'),
         url('ballw___.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('ballw___.svg#ballparkweiner') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}


h2 { margin: 0px; text-align: center; font-size: 40px; color: #FFFFFF; font-family: Cambria;}

body {background-color: #000000;}

h3 {text-align: center; color: #FFFFFF; }

#footer { font-weight: bold; text-align: center; font-family: Audimat;
    clear: both; width:48%;
        border-radius: 8px;
        background-color:black;
        text-align:center; margin-right:auto;
        margin-left:auto; color: #FFFFFF; }
```

From the information I gathered on-line, most said to use font-weight: lighter;

but that doesn't validate when I use the css validator. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try numbers? `font-weight: 100;/*200,300,400*/`

Comment: Yes, I tried numbers and h1 did not change in size.

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
h1 { font-weight: normal; }
```

By default, browsers use `bold` weight for `h1`. Since your `@font-face` declares only `normal` weight typeface, (some) browsers will algorithmically bold the glyphs (i.e., make the strokes wider using some simple method).

Answer (score 0):

I checked your css validate, where did you checked? Probably you checked for css2 validation. Check here this one is original/best http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator

Answer (score 0):

I actually just added the font weight line (I had it under the @font face instead )

```
h1 {color: #FFFFFF; font-family: ballparkweiner; font-size: 110px;
text-align: center; margin: 0px; font-weight: lighter; }
```